# Launch Activity without clicking the tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost contains `4 activities`.

```
1===>>show my appointments

2===>>set Appointment 

3===>>Block calender

4===>>other.
```

> `1.I need to launch the set appointment from the show my appointment by passing some data (but tabhost should be remains)`
>
> `2. From the dash board if want to open set appointment in tabhost but internally its executing all activities in tabhost how can I avoid this if I am coming from the dash board to tabhost`.

I used the `tabHost.setCurrentTab(SetAppointment );`

But internally its execeuing the other activity's also but that should not be happen.

```
  public class ShowMyAppointments extends Activity implements OnClickListener
  {

 //     in list selection  the below code

  else if(showItems[selectedPosition].equals("ReSchedule")){

                                String appointmentId = String.valueOf(appointmentsList.get(SELECTED_PATIENT).getId());
                                String statusCode = Constants.STATUS_CANCLEED_DOCTOR;               

                                new SatusAsunc(ShowMyAppointments.this ,appointmentId , statusCode).execute();  

                                HomeGridViewActivity.value=1;                        
                                Constants.CONSUMER_ID=appointmentsList.get(SELECTED_PATIENT).getConsumerID();                        
                                Constants.CONTACT_NO=appointmentsList.get(SELECTED_PATIENT).getConsumerContact();
                                Constants.PATIENT_NAME=appointmentsList.get(SELECTED_PATIENT).getConsumerName();                    
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ShowMyAppointments.this , BaseActivity.class);                    
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call these two methods from show my appointments activity to call set appointments activity

```
 TabActivity _parentActivity=(TabActivity) getParent();
_parentActivity.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1); //index of set appointments
        _parentActivity.onTabChanged("set appointment");   //Please provide tabSpaceName here  of set appointment name
```

If you want to send some data with intent then try this

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(name, value);
    _parentActivity.startActivityFromChild(childActivity, intent, requestCode);  //childActivity =show my appointment   requestCode=0  or any thing else
```

Comment: The method onTabChanged(String) is undefined for the type TabActivity i am getting this error

Comment: please call this method in  "show my appointments activity"  because it is child activity of your tab host